# Get left and top margin of imageview after calling scrollby

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I am using `image.scrollBy` to move image drawable.

However after calling `image.getLeft()` as well as `image.getLayoutParams().leftMargin` it returns 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: if the your image has position (top, left) in (0, 0) and you have not give any margin, it is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

I think you call `image.getLayoutParams().leftMargin` and `image.getLeft()` into the constructor or into the `onCreate` of your `Activity` !

Return 0 because you call this during the initilization of your object !
For get the correct value, you should to call that outside `onCreate` and the constructor.

During `onCreate` and the constructor, the view isn't initialized and the activity doesn't know the size of a view if the param is `wrap_content`/`fill_parent`/`match_parent`.

You can use the getting size method only after the initialization of your view.